# Android Http proxy using ProxyDroid not working on some applications. Rooted device

Tags: android, proxy, burp

I can proxy almost every application but there are some that won't even make a connection when either the system proxy is set via `Wlan` -> `Modify network config` or using the `Global Proxy` setting from `ProxyDroid`.

I guess these applications are somehow monitoring that a proxy is used even with [ProxyDriod](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.proxydroid&hl=sv) on a rooted phone. The applications work as normal when the proxy is turned off. When turned on the applications are not making a single request, they just return an error code. The error code is identical as if Wifi and Celluar data is turned off.

Sample of applications affected:

- BankId
- Handelsbanken Privat
- Facebook - does not throw an error but no requests are shown. If functions like search are used an error is thrown

Mobile used for proxying:

- Samsung Galaxy Note 4 SM-N910F
- Android 6.0.1
- Rooted using CF-Auto-Root

Burp is used as a proxy listener and has been set up using these guides and normal HTTPS sites works without a warning.

https://support.portswigger.net/customer/portal/articles/1841101-configuring-an-android-device-to-work-with-burp

https://support.portswigger.net/customer/portal/articles/1841102-Mobile%20Set-up_Android%20Device%20-%20Installing%20CA%20Certificate.html

What is the most probable way that these applications check if a proxy is used?  Has anyone else experienced this and managed to bypass proxy evasion from an Android App?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the applications does not check for a proxy but rather they check the certificate using `SSL pinning`, which is really great except for my purpose.

More about [certificate pinning](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29988/what-is-certificate-pinning).

Here is what I did to get it working:

Install CWM custom recovery. I used this guide for this:

http://www.droidopinions.com/install-cwm-custom-recovery-galaxy-note-4-models/

I then followed this guide to install the Xposed framework:

https://devs-lab.com/download-install-xposed-for-samsung-devices.html

Then I installed `JustTrustMe` from Github:

https://github.com/Fuzion24/JustTrustMe

After enabeling the module and restarting the phone I could proxy every application without trouble.

Here is a great guide for proxying Android applications:

https://secvibe.com/android-appsec-27855dca8531#.ta66ox3di

**Note:**

I also tried installing `Cydia Substrate` from Android Play Store and then install the apk for [Android TrustKiller](https://github.com/iSECPartners/Android-SSL-TrustKiller). However this did not work for me. From Cydia Substrate I got the error

> "Something about your device made it impossible for substrate to
>   perform its internal safety check; can you please contact saurik via
>   e-mail?"

Also Android TrustKiller has not been updated for three years.